# failed: Connection reset by peer

Tags: cassandra, netty, cassandra-3.0, datastax-java-driver

I have been using apache cassandra 3.0.11

- Datastax driver: 3.1.3
- Netty version: 4.1.6.Final

We get the frequent below error in the database side:

```
INFO  [SharedPool-Worker-2] 2017-09-11 01:39:31,738 Message.java:615 - Unexpected exception during request; channel = [id: 0x22d0c179, L:/xx.xx.xx.xx:9042 ! R:/yy.yy.yy.yy:57774]
io.netty.channel.unix.Errors$NativeIoException: syscall:read(...)() failed: Connection reset by peer
        at io.netty.channel.unix.FileDescriptor.readAddress(...)(Unknown Source) ~[netty-all-4.0.44.Final.jar:4.0.44.Final]
INFO  [SharedPool-Worker-2] 2017-09-11 01:44:25,789 Message.java:615 - Unexpected exception during request; channel = [id: 0xace60b99, L:/xx.xx.xx.xx:9042 ! R:/yy.yy.yy.yy:54372]
io.netty.channel.unix.Errors$NativeIoException: syscall:read(...)() failed: Connection reset by peer
        at io.netty.channel.unix.FileDescriptor.readAddress(...)(Unknown Source) ~[netty-all-4.0.44.Final.jar:4.0.44.Final]
```

And from the application side we get the below error:

```
08/24/17 05:30:08.321   DEBUG [CassandraAccessor:57] - executing CQL [select * from src where host_ip= 'cc.cc.cc.cc']
08/24/17 05:30:08.319   DEBUG [Qwerty:49] - Finding route for [ Source IP : yy.yy.yy.yy , Source Port : 16107 , Messaage Type : ISONMQ
08/24/17 05:30:08.322   DEBUG [CassandraAccessor:57] - executing CQL [select * from test]
08/24/17 05:30:08.321   ERROR [RequestHandler$SpeculativeExecution$1:333] - Unexpected error while querying /xx.xx.xx.xx
com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.ConnectionException: [/xx.xx.xx.xx:9042] Pool is CLOSING
        at com.datastax.driver.core.HostConnectionPool.borrowConnection(HostConnectionPool.java:196)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler$SpeculativeExecution.query(RequestHandler.java:293)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler$SpeculativeExecution.findNextHostAndQuery(RequestHandler.java:272)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler.startNewExecution(RequestHandler.java:115)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler.sendRequest(RequestHandler.java:95)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.SessionManager.executeAsync(SessionManager.java:132)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.AbstractSession.execute(AbstractSession.java:68)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.AbstractSession.execute(AbstractSession.java:43)
        at org.springframework.cassandra.core.CqlTemplate$3.doInSession(CqlTemplate.java:286)
        at org.springframework.cassandra.core.CqlTemplate$3.doInSession(CqlTemplate.java:283)
        at org.springframework.cassandra.core.CqlTemplate.doExecute(CqlTemplate.java:276)
        at org.springframework.cassandra.core.CqlTemplate.doExecuteQueryReturnResultSet(CqlTemplate.java:283)
        at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.CassandraTemplate.select(CassandraTemplate.java:594)
        at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.CassandraTemplate.select(CassandraTemplate.java:376)
        at com.fs.searshc.commlink.db.cassandra.RouterData.findBySourceIp(RouterData.java:27)
        at com.fs.searshc.commlink.router.tcpip.CommLinkRouter.findRoute(CommLinkRouter.java:75)
```

Any kind of help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Connection reset by peer means that the remote peer forcible closed the connection. So you need to find out why it did it.

Comment: Thanks Norman for the response. Its a cluster and the node which closed the connection is also a part of the cluster. Is there a way to find out why peer nodes are closing the connection forcibly?

Comment: You will check on the peer and may be able to better understand the issue when using something like tcpdump or wireshark

Comment: As suggested by Norman we have run tcpdump and got the below output.

Comment: we have run tcpdump and got the below output.
Application server: xx.xx.xx.139
Cassandra server1: xx.xx.xx.78
cassandra server2: xx.xx.xx.79

TCP dump from application server:xx.xx.xx.139

2017-09-20 05:09:22.170273 IP xx.xx.xx.78.9042 > xx.xx.xx.139.44408: Flags [R.], seq 558647898, ack 47750391, win 6145, options [nop,nop,TS val 3419854254 ecr 1293665900], length 0
2017-09-20 05:09:22.170319 IP xx.xx.xx.79.9042 > xx.xx.xx.139.42696: Flags [R.], seq 594588671, ack 44660661, win 6146, options [nop,nop,TS val 3410573711 ecr 1293665900], length 0

Comment: Can someone help me with decoding tcpdump output.
I want to know which host is tthe culprit here and sending RESET.

Comment: any response for that !!